# Security issues if I post username in comments on my website?

Tags: web-application, user-names

When users try to log in to my web application they have two options: their username or their email including password, both of them are unique.

When the logged-in user tries to write comments in the public comment box, shall I post his/her username as a name or ask them to write their name? What can I do for better security?

If I post their username as a name, their account is at risk since a hacker can take the username and try to login with it.

Comment: The username isn't secret, the password is.

Comment: Seems like more of a privacy issue, but even then, people voluntarily advertise their username or even real name all the time online.

Answer (score 3):

A solution to your conundrum is having two separate handles for login and for display. Steam is a prominent example for this pattern. Users log in with their `account name`, while only the `player name` is displayed in forums or when playing with other users.

For this measure to be effective, you must ensure that those names cannot be the same. An attacker can harvest `player names` as much as he want, because only the `account name` can be used to log in.

You should be aware though, that user names are usually not treated as a secret and users are likely to leak them anyway. Your security should **not** revolve around keeping user names secret. A solid 2FA is all you need for state of the art user authentication.